# Checking the original type of a converted object

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to know if it's possible to get the original type of an object when held through a pointer to base class.

For example:

```
class Base {
  virtual void f() = 0
};
class Derived: public Base {};

Base * ptr=new Derived;
//if I use
cout << typeid(ptr).name(); //prints Base*
```

I want it to print the original type "Derived". Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You didn't *convert* `Derived` to `Base`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the static and dynamic type of `ptr` are both `Base *`. However, for `*ptr`, the situation is different. The static type is `Base &`, but the dynamic type is `Derived &`. So that's what you want to test:

```
cout << typeid(*ptr).name();
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `dynamic_cast`

```
if(Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b1))
{
    std::cout << "downcast from b1 to d successful\n";
    d->name(); // safe to call
}
```

Be careful as this is often seen as a bad practice, and you shouldn't really do it. You don't `need` the derived type class, try to think in terms of interfaces.